# Android seekbar remove shadow from thumb

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a seekbar for a calculator app I'm making. I'm relatively new to android studio and can't figure out how to remove the little shadow from the thumb of the seekbar when you click it. I want the seekbar to be completely invisible, yet the little shadow always appears when I click on it.

[Little shadow Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDCJ5.png)

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set null in `android:background` attribute.

```
<SeekBar
    android:background="@null"
     ... />
```